# Composition of linear maps as a tensor product

Tags: tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

$\mathbf{Question:}$
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over an algebraically closed field $F$.  Fix $A,B \in \mathscr{L}(V)$.  Consider the linear operator $T_{A,B} \in \mathscr{L}(\mathscr{L}(V))$ such that $T_{A,B}(X) = AX + XB$.  Express $T_{A,B} $in terms of tensor products using the identification of $\mathscr{L}(V)$ with $V^*\otimes V$.

$\mathbf{Answer:}  A \otimes I + I \otimes B^*$

Please explain. Every time I pick up this problem again I feel like I'm just blindly manipulating expressions. Thank you!